# Ruby on Rails HTML outputting extra characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone please tell me where the extra characters are coming from?

Here's what the output looks like: http://screencast.com/t/f0sgNPzMu

I don't quite understand where all the extra characters are coming from.

Here are my files:

```
    ##application.html.erb

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title><%= title %></title>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="container">
          <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
          <section class="round">
            <%= yield %>
          </section>
          <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
          <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
        </div>
      </body>
     </html>
 
##_header.html.erb
    <header>
     <%= link_to logo, root_path %>
     <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Help', help_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Sign in', '#' %></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
     </header>
```

### home.html.erb

```
 <h1>Sample App</h1>
 <p>
 This is the home page
 </p>
 <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, :class => "signup_button round" %>
```

Here's the HTML page source:

```
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="container">
          <header>
       <a href="/"><img alt="Sample App" class="round" src="/assets/logo.png" /></a>
       <nav>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
     </header>
 
          <section class="round">
            <h1>Sample App</h1>
      <p>
       This is the home page
      </p>
      <a href="/signup" class="signup_button round">Sign up now!</a>
 
 
          </section>
          <footer>
      <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
       <li>
        <a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/news">News</a></li>
       <li>
        <a href='http://rails.tutorials.org'>Rails Tutorial</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
      </footer>
 
          <pre class='debug_dump'>--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
controller: pages
action: home
          </pre>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please put together an actual question, rather then "omg look at all my files"

Comment: Please include a minimal example in the question, too.

Comment: There's a screenshot of what the page looks like in the question along with the templates and the HTML source. What else am I missing? What would you like to see?

Comment: I think what they're asking for is not links, but for you to include those things in this page. *WHEN* those links break, your question will be worthless to future visitors searching for the same problem. Embed the information into your question and it'll live a long time. As is, you're asking us to do extra work looking up your pages just to help you.

Comment: Makes sense. Have made the necessary changes. However one needs to take a look at the screenshot to see the extra characters I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem might be in the CSS.

Check, if you have the content-attribute activated for links.

Maybe this helps: http://davidwalsh.name/optimize-your-links-for-print-using-css-show-url or http://www.alistapart.com/articles/improvingprint

Comment: Hmm looks like it did have something to do with CSS. It was my application.css

Comment: Pressed Add Comment too early. Here's my code:
https://gist.github.com/6b770611114f28ff4096

Answer (score 2):

Remove the

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

line and your debug informations should not be visible anymore